# Enqueue in Phonon no longer working

Tags: qt, phonon

After a recent software update to the phonon libraries, I've noticed that a media playing application that I wrote is no longer able to loop tracks.  The code in question is below.  The first track is set, and once it nears completion it is set to play again.

```
void Alarm::Start(bool useCustom)
{
    if(useCustom)
    {
        media->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(this->_CustPath));
        this->_UsingCustomPath=true;
    }else{
     FileIO::ExtractAudio();
     media->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(this->_DefaultPath));
     this->_UsingCustomPath=false;
    }

    media->play();
    connect(media,SIGNAL(aboutToFinish()),this,SLOT(RepeatAllTheThings()));
    this->_isPlaying=true;
}

void Alarm::RepeatAllTheThings()
{
    if(this->_UsingCustomPath)
    {
       media->enqueue(this->_CustPath);
    }else{
        media->enqueue(this->_DefaultPath);
    }
}
```

After running through the debugger a few times I noticed this message:

```
"Ignoring source as no aboutToFinish handling is in progress"
```

A quick google search doesn't tell much about this message.  It looks like a check for a private variable (that I dont have access to) has been added ([a diff of the file](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file?file=PHONON_GSTREAMER_46_BRANCH.diff&package=phonon-backend-gstreamer-0_10&project=openSUSE:12.2%3aARM&rev=161df664f97c84f710407d66c90b706f))

Does anyone know if I just discovered a new bug in phonon, or am I some how using the enqueue method incorrectly?

EDIT:
The code above only fails about 1/2 the time.  Very confused.  Currently running phonon-gstreamer 4.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with this work-around:

```
media->play();
connect(media,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(RepeatAllTheThings()));



void Alarm::RepeatAllTheThings()
{
    if(this->_UsingCustomPath)
    {
        media->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(this->_CustPath));
    }else{
        media->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(this->_DefaultPath));
    }
    media->play();
}
```

Comment: If using this, there are a black slash when switching the videos (no gapless playback)